# Laravel Duplication Of data

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a laravel project were when submitting a form, I am getting a value from a column name x and incrementing it by 1 and submitting,

It works fine, but on production when I open two browsers and submit both forms at a time - it gets duplicated, I have also added a validation to check the unique data

but it won't work if I submit multiple forms at a time

I am not that much expert in laravel - do I need to look on Pessimistic Locking ??

Can someone give me a suggestion?

Comment: It _almost_ sounds like you want an auto-incrementing column?

Comment: What does it mean exactly "it gets duplicated"?

Comment: @James not an auto incrementation, need to getting a column data and using an algorithm to increment it

Comment: @MartinOsusky not an auto incrementation, need to getting a column data and using an algorithm to increment it

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel's atomic lock to lock the data on the unique data points.

Only one of the requests will be allowed at a time.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#atomic-locks

Comment: thank for your answer, i am using laravel 5 still , will it get supported

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to dispatch the job in one queue. In Laravel, I would prefer this particular solution.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dispatching-jobs

Comment: thanks for your answer, when i submit i need to show the response to user , so i cannot use a queue where it will take some time, there is a issue on the user experience